# Rally Rest Api: Query for all children, grandchildren,

Tags: c#, web-services, api, rest, rally

I'm trying to retrieve a user story be its formattedID with all its children, the children of the children, etc...

I was having problems to retrieve the RevisionHistory and the Revisions, but the `ProjectScopeDown` property worked. What is needed in order to get all the child tree?

My query right is looks like:

```
Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement")
            {
                ProjectScopeUp = false,
                ProjectScopeDown = true,
                Fetch = new List<string>() 
                {
                    "Name",
                    "ObjectID",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "LastUpdateDate", 
                    "Owner", 
                    "Children", 
                    "Description", 
                    "RevisionHistory", 
                    "Revisions"
                },
                Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, _formattedID)
            };

            try
            {
                QueryResult queryStoryResults = m_rallyApi.Query(storyRequest);
                if (queryStoryResults.Results.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var myStory = queryStoryResults.Results.First();

                    userStory = new HierarchicalRequirement(myStory);
                }
            }
```

I could get the other child by checking the `DirectChildrenCount` and getting them by reference, but I would like to avoid this multiples call to the web service and bring everything in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For server performance reasons hierarchy is limited to one level in WSAPI queries.  Queries like yours (including all revision history and revisions for an entire story hierarchy) are a good example of a super expensive request.

You'll need to recurse down the tree for each story, fetching children while there are still children left to read.

Comment: Thank you very much. I my mind, I though that one big request to the server was better than multiple small ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example illustrating a recursive query that walks a Story Hierarchy per Kyle's suggestion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace RestExample_QueryStoryHierarchy
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // This will be the FormattedID of the top-level story from which we want to start traversing down
            string queryFormattedID = "US1";

            Console.WriteLine("Starting to walk Story Tree at: " + queryFormattedID);
            WalkTree.queryStoryTree(queryFormattedID);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished walking the tree...");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    // Class with Static function to recursively walk a story tree
    static class WalkTree
    {
        public static void queryStoryTree(string inputFormattedID)
        {
            //Query for items
            Request request = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
            request.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "Description",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "Children"
                };

            // Query Rally for Story
            request.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, inputFormattedID);

            RallyRestApi restApi = rallyRestApiRef.getRestApi;
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

            // Grab story Children and process each Child
            foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Parent:");
                Console.WriteLine(result["Name"]);
                var resultChildren = result["Children"];
                foreach (var resultChild in resultChildren)
                {
                    string childFormattedID = resultChild["FormattedID"];
                    string childName = resultChild["Name"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Child/Grandchild Name:");
                    Console.WriteLine(childName);

                    // Call self recursively on Children to continue walking the tree
                    queryStoryTree(childFormattedID);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Static class providing reference to Rally to other member Classes
    static class rallyRestApiRef
    {
        private static String userName = "user@company.com";
        private static String userPassword = "topsecret";
        private static String serverUrl = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        private static String wsapiVersion = "1.43";

        private static RallyRestApi _restApi =
            new RallyRestApi(userName,
                             userPassword,
                             serverUrl,
                             wsapiVersion);

        public static RallyRestApi getRestApi
        {
            get { return _restApi; }
        }
    }
}
```